# what is the full Teradata Client software?

Tags: teradata

I read couple of online documents to get start with the Teradata basics.

I am curious to know what is full client version of Teradata client software to install on Windows/unix/Linux environments? What is best suited for client install?

I see different client versions depends on the type drivers/applications

```
1. Teradata JDBC
2. Teradata ODBC
3. Teradata dot net provider
4. Teradata SQl assist/BTSE
5. Teradata Express
6. Teradata OLE DB provider
7. TTU .... etc
```

To more clarity on my Question .. DB2 and Oracle have a full client software which can install locally on windows/unix systems and it will be able to use or all type connectivity(odbc,jdbc,ole db,ado .net...etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical base toolset for end users/developers submitting ad hoc queries from each environment:

**Windows** ([TTU 13.10 Client Install](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-tools-and-utilities-windows-installation-package) - 400MB)

- Teradata SQL Assistant
- Teradata .Net Provider and/or ODBC Driver
- Teradata GSS & ICU Libraries
- (Optional) WinBTEQ
- (Optional) Teradata CLI - for WinBTEQ

**Linux/UNIX/Mac OS X**

- Teradata JDBC Driver
- Teradata Studio Express
- (Optional - if using Eclipse)Teradata Plug-in for Eclipse

Many of these components can be found in the Teradata Developer's Exchange [Downloads](http://downloads.teradata.com/download) section. Starting with Teradata 12 they have reset the version numbers in an attempt to address the confusion with the different development life cycles of each component contained within their Tools and Utilities. Tools for Teradata 13.x should be compatible with Teradata 12 and Teradata 14. However, certain features specific to a given database release may not be available unless you are using a version of the client that is equal to or greater than the database version.

For ETL Development, then you will be relying upon the BTEQ, FastLoad, FastExport, MultiLoad combined with the Teradata CLI to connect to Teradata.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for **Windows** only.
To run queries against a Teradata database, you need the following:

1. Teradata SQL Assistant
2. Teradata .NET Data provider
3. Teradata ODBC Driver

To know, if your system has Teradata ODBC Driver, goto Control Panel, Administrative Tools -> Data Sources -> Add and see if Teradata is listed.

Sample screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on new database and ( if you have license to use ), you can have a look at Teradata parallel transporter. It provides extract-load capabilities with configurable scripts.